# Yii2: can't create sql command using innerJoin

Tags: yii2

I am not that good at `SQL` but i do as much as i can for the little knowledge i have..

I have made a single a flat `SQL` string with the help from a friend that gathers data from a table using a relative table from an initial data from the first table, the `SQL` was made like this:

```
SELECT id, username, auth_assignment.created_at
FROM `user` JOIN `auth_assignment`
ON (user.id = auth_assignment.user_id)
JOIN `auth_item`
ON (auth_item.name = auth_assignment.item_name)
WHERE auth_item.name = 'Admin'
```

the initial data to look is `Admin` so everything works in that side, but i tried to simulate this `SQL` using `Yii2` functions.. so far i have made this code

```
$query = new Query;

$command = $query->select('id, username')
    ->innerJoin('auth_assignment', ['user.id'=>'auth_assignment.user_id'])
    ->innerJoin('auth_item', ['auth_item.name'=>'auth_assignment.item_name'])
    ->where('auth_item.name = :name', [':name'=>$name])->createCommand();

var_dump($command->query());
```

this returns an `SQLSTATE` error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `auth_assignment` ON `user`.`id`='auth_assignment.user_id' INNER JOIN' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `id`, `username` INNER JOIN `auth_assignment` ON `user`.`id`='auth_assignment.user_id' INNER JOIN `auth_item` ON `auth_item`.`name`='auth_assignment.item_name' WHERE auth_item.name = 'Admin'
```

i checked the method `$command->sql;` to know how the `SQL` was being generated.. but i really don't know how to fix it due to my lack of my knowledge to `SQL` and lack of understanding to `yii2` api documentation

`SQL` is generated like this:

```
SELECT `id`, `username` INNER JOIN `auth_assignment` ON `user`.`id`=:qp1 INNER JOIN `auth_item` ON `auth_item`.`name`=:qp2 WHERE auth_item.name = :name
```

i appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Query

```
$query = (new yii\db\Query())
         ->select('id, username, auth_assignment.created_at')
         ->from('user')
         ->innerJoin('auth_assignment','user.id=auth_assignment.user_id')
         ->innerJoin('auth_item','auth_item.name = auth_assignment.item_name')
         ->where([
               'auth_item.name' => 'Admin'
         ])->all();
```